# After AJAX request page isnt re rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My posts in blogs_controller can be selected by flairs. Flairs can be selected with drop down. When I any other option is selected, then page is being reloaded with ajax and everything works fine, but if I press the submit button, which should send empty `:flair` value and render page and table again, but it sends, I see how all posts are selected, but nothing changes, why?
I'm really can't get this.

```
#blog_controller.rb
  def index

    @blogs = Blog.order("created_at desc")

    if !(params[:flair].blank?)
      @blogs = @blogs.where(:flair => params[:flair])
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:name, :title, :content, :flair)
  end
```

```
#index.html.haml
%h1 Listing blogs

= form_with method: :get do |f|
  = f.select :flair, @flairs, {},{onchange: "this.form.submit()"}
  = f.submit 'Clear', params: {flair: ""}

= render 'table'
%br
```

```
#_table.html.haml
%table#table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th Title
      %th Content
      %th Flair

  %tbody
    - @blogs.each do |blog|
      %tr
        %td= blog.name
        %td= blog.title
        %td= blog.content
        %td= blog.flair
        %td= link_to 'Show', blog
        %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog)
        %td= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your request is expecting a JS response, and since you don't handle this in your controller it defaults to HTML. The HTML will not be re-rendered unless you reload the page on submit so "nothing happens" in the UI even though the controller method is called.

Comment: Ok, I will add `index.js.haml`, but why then selector works?

Comment: The easiest way to debug these things is to inspect the requests you're sending in with something like this in the controller method: `raise request.headers.inspect`. My hunch is that you're acutally reloading the page and not actually using Ajax, hard to tell without debugging.

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about `raise`? How to use it and where i can find documentation.

Comment: There is not a lot of documentation on it https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/raise because it is quite simply method to force a RunTimeError anywhere in the code. It's good to use for debugging purposes, or even return a 500 if you reach a part of the code you should never come to.